# Rails Controller Integration Test - Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <500: Internal Server Error>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Working in ruby '2.5.7' and rails '5.2.3'.

I am having trouble passing the "get index" test for my controller test (code below). I am not sure what is the problem because the other test "get about" works just fine.

Here's my Controller Test file:

```
class HomeControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should get index" do
    get home_path
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get about_path
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

Here's the outcome after running "rails test":

```
HomeControllerTest
  test_should_get_about                                           PASS (0.03s)

HomeControllerTest
  test_should_get_index                                           FAIL (0.13s)
Minitest::Assertion:         Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <500: Internal Server Error>
        test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:HomeControllerTest>'
```

If it helps, this is my routes.rb file in the config folder:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'home', to: 'home#index', as: :home
  get 'home/about', to: 'home#about', as: :about

end
```

This is my home_controller.rb file:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def about
    end

end
```

And lastly, I have the following files in my views directory:

- home/about.html.erb
- home/index.html.erb

I've tried a lot of things but none of them seem to resolve this issue. I'm mainly baffled as to why the "about" test is working while the "index" test is not (even though they're both handled in a similar manner...)

Thank you!

Comment: Any number of errors in the controller and view can cause the controller to return a Internal Server Error. Its literally the most abstract error ever. We have nothing to go on except that something is broken. You'll have to either improve you're own troubleshooting skills or give us the whole picture with the route, controller and view so that we can actually reproduce and diagnose the issue.

Comment: What is in your 'home/index.html.erb'? Do you have the error when get `/home` via browser?

Comment: Thank you @Vasilisa! You're a great help!  
Indeed it was a problem with 'home/index.html.erb' as I had accidentally included a path that was not in 'routes.rb'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized my stupid mistake

Thank you @Vasilisa for pointing me in the right direction!

In 'home/index.html.erb' (within my views directory), I had accidentally referenced another path that was not listed in my 'routes.rb' file. Removing that from 'home/index.html.erb' immediately resolved the problem. This explains why my "about" test was working but my "index" test was not...

(Previously I wasn't aware that the controller test would care about the contents of the Views - especially when my controller test is so basic.)

Comment: Happy to help :) I'm not a big expert in MiniTest (working with Rspec almost always), but I think there should be a kind of test without view rendering. But you use `IntegrationTest` it tests the whole app interaction and renders views